# The download button for the image output in Gradio malfunctions when embedded

Tags: javascript, html, embedding, huggingface, gradio

The output window of Gradio has a small down arrow icon to download the output image. When I run my Gradio app directly on Huggingface, this button works correctly by downloading the image directly through the browser. However, when I embed the application within an HTML, that button no longer works the same way. When you click on it, it opens the image in the browser. This is not the expected behavior, since loading the image directly in the browser resets the entire app window when you return, and it should not behave this way. Any workaround to avoid or fix this behavior?

[image]